# Solving one Systems Equations, Research Level Questions?!

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, maple

We have three equations as follows:

$A_p=F \cos(\alpha+ \phi) - \mu N^{'}_{S_1} - \mu N_{S_1}  - W \sin \theta = m ( \ddot x - r \ddot \theta (\sin (\gamma+ \phi)) )$

$B_p=F \cos(\alpha+ \phi) - \mu N^{'}_{S_1} + \mu N_{S_1}  - W \cos \theta = m ( -r \ddot \theta (\sin (\gamma + \phi)) )$

$C_p=F e_G \cos \alpha + F \sin \alpha(x_G-l_1)+ N^{'}_{S_1} (x_G-l_1-a ) \cos \phi - N_{s_1}(x_G-l_1-a-s_1)\cos \phi +\mu N^{'}_{S_1} (h_1+ \frac{d}{2}-e_g) \cos \phi - \mu N_{S_1} (h_1+ \frac{d}{2}+e_g) \cos \phi = I_G \ddot \phi $

> the unknown is $N_{S_1},  N^{'}_{S_1},\ddot \phi(t), \phi(t) $. I
>   think (not sure) we can replace $\phi(t)= \frac{1}{2}  \ddot
> > \phi(t)\cdot t^2$.

Infact I want to solve the following:

---

$A_p=(1.051250801 \times 10^6t-9.885179829 \times 10^6 t^2+ 4.744120386 \times 10^7 t^3 - 1.282599777 \times 10^8 t^4 + 1.970136609 \times 10^8t^5 - 1.604249861 \times 10^8 t^6 + 5.377070775 \times 10^7 t^7) \Bigg(  \cos \Bigg(  \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg ) - \sin \Bigg( \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg) \phi(t) \Bigg ) - 0.16 N^{'}_{s_1} - 0.16 N_{s_1} - 3534.543 \sin \Big( \frac{1}{18} \pi \Big)=42628.97791 - 157.3659448 \Bigg ( \frac {d^2}{dt^2} \phi (t) \Bigg)  (0.3068020853 + 0.9517733346 \phi(t))    $

---

$B_p=(1.051250801 \times 10^6t-9.885179829 \times 10^6 t^2+ 4.744120386 \times 10^7 t^3 - 1.282599777 \times 10^8 t^4 + 1.970136609 \times 10^8t^5 - 1.604249861 \times 10^8 t^6 + 5.377070775 \times 10^7 t^7) \Bigg(  \sin \Bigg(  \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg ) +\cos \Bigg( \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg) \phi(t) \Bigg ) - 0.16 N^{'}_{s_1} + 0.16 N_{s_1} - 3534.543 \cos \Big( \frac{1}{18} \pi \Big)=-157.3659448 \Bigg ( \Bigg ( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \phi(t) \Bigg ) (0.3068020853 + 0.9517733346 \phi(t)) \Bigg)    $

---

$C_p=0.006(1.051250801 \times 10^6t-9.885179829 \times 10^6 t^2+ 4.744120386 \times 10^7 t^3 - 1.282599777 \times 10^8 t^4 + 1.970136609 \times 10^8t^5 - 1.604249861 \times 10^8 t^6 + 5.377070775 \times 10^7 t^7) \cos \Bigg( \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg)+ 1.5485 (1.051250801 \times 10^6t-9.885179829 \times 10^6t^2+4.744120386 \times 10^7 t^3 - 1.282599777 \times 10^8 t^4 + 1.97013660910 \times 10^8 t^5 + 5.377070775 \times 10^7 t^7) 
  \sin \Bigg(  \frac {1}{1800} \pi \Bigg )  + 0.4157 N^{'}_{s_1} - 0.0127 N_{s_1} + 0.16 N^{'}_{s_1} (0.3000000000) - 0.16 N_{s_1} (0.3120000000) = 229.38 \Bigg ( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \phi(t) \Bigg )  $

> I want to solve this problem, I ran into this question from my two
>   month research on my works, anyone can help me? is it possible to
>   solve it via MAPLE or other things to get solutions for this complex
>   problem? I means how can calculate the $\phi$? or at least very good approximation?

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? Are these equations obtained from a mechanical set-up of some sort, in which case there may be easier ways of doing it.

Comment: Yes it's mechanical question, @DavidQuinn

Comment: Are you expecting closed form solution in terms of elementary functions? Does your mechanical system have some conserved quantities or is it purely dissipative?

Comment: You seem to have 4 equations and 3 unknowns, correct? If $\phi(t)$ is known then its second derivative is known. Also why don't you just compute $\phi(t)$ from the ODE that it satisfies?

Comment: @okrzysik $\phi(t)$ is unknown, we can wrote it via other unknowns as I mentioned. I want the solution in Radian or Degree. $\phi(t)$ is rotation.

Comment: From solving the ODE: $\phi(t) = A t^2 + B/t$ where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: @Evgeny I want to calculate it as Radian or Degree for last answer, If we cannot solve it, we want to approximate it very carefully.

Comment: @okrzysik I couldn't solve it, would you please consider more detail?

Comment: @okrzysik we have 3 equations.

Comment: if any more detail need, i come back next two hours when I arrived home.

Comment: Can you provide a statement of the original problem, a diagram preferably, and an explanation of what all these letters represent?

Comment: @MichleNiaye the ODE is an [Euler-Cauchy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Euler_equation). You may solve it by searching for a solution of the form $\phi = t^{\alpha}$. Substitute this into the equation and generate an algebraic equation for $\alpha$.

Comment: Anyone could improve my question to find this research question?

Comment: @okrzysik would you please describe it for me?

Comment: @MichleNiaye describe what exactly?

Comment: you say this can be solved by ODE... Is it possible describe it more? my filed is mechanical not math.  @okrzysik

Comment: @MichleNiaye previously the post included the equation $\phi(t)= 1/2 \ddot \phi(t)\cdot t^2$. I simply said this is an Euler-Cauchy ODE (ordinary differential equation) and you may solve it to deduce the quantity $\phi(t)$. As to how to solve this single ODE please read my previous comment or follow the link that I provided in that comment (alternatively, google the EC ODE for yourself).

Comment: how we can get help that someone to implement it via one math software? @okrzysik I didn't have enough time to learn and try to solve it via complex method that you mentioned. thanks

Comment: I do not know, I do not even understand the question that you're asking of me. I've already explicitly written the solution of the ODE in a previous comment and told you how to solve it for yourself.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, but I didnt enough information in MATH so need someone help it more for me.